# C# Linq group by DateTime ignore hours and minutes

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by, sum

I have a SortedList that has DateTime for the key and int for the value. The DateTime value will have the hour and minute attached. Is it possible to write a C# linq procedure to group the SortedList by a single Date ignoring the hour and sum-up the value?

Answer (score 7):

With LINQ it is pretty straightforward:

```
from item in list
group item by item.Key.Date into g
select new 
{
   Sum = g.Sum(a => a.Value),
   Values = g
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By a single date?

Easy!

Assuming you have declared the variable `singleDate` as a `DateTime` to get the sum of, here is the query:

```
var result = (
        from key in sortedList.Keys.Cast<DateTime>()
        where key.Date == singleDate.Date
        select (int)sortedList[key]
    ).Sum();
```

I've used `singleDate.Date` to drop any time information that `singleDate` may have, but otherwise this should be fairly straight forward.

`SortedList` is a little painful to work with LINQ. Can you tell me why you are using it?